# Oracle ADF GANTT DIAGRAM, TIMEAXIS WIDTH

Tags: java, oracle-adf

how can I change the width of timeaxis in gantt component. For scale i selected week and days.

                    
                
                
                    
                
I want't to increase width of days scale. This is how mine scale look Time axis gantt and the tasks are to small. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:
binding to managed bean  (gantt)
in set method do this:

```
this.gantt = gantt;
this.gantt.setMinWidth(1600);
```